# what is the correct lines of code for addition program by taking input from user?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Today i downloaded my new python 3.8.5 version 32 bit in 64 bit PC and tried a simple addition program.
This is my code:

```
value = input("Please enter a string:\n")
value2 = input("Please enter a string:\n")
value3 = value+value2
print(f'You entered {value+value2}')
print(f'You entered {value3}')
```

This is the result:

```
= RESTART: C:\Users\mcheg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\trial_later delete filie1.py
Please enter a string:
12
Please enter a string:
34
You entered 1234
You entered 1234
```

Comment: I mean, you entered two _strings_ (and you know they're strings!), then concatenated them with `value+value2` and got another string. This is what's supposed to happen

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the inputs to `int`. By default, input values are string

```
value = int(input("Please enter a string:\n"))
value2 = int(input("Please enter a string:\n"))
value3 = value+value2
print(f'You entered {value+value2}')
print(f'You entered {value3}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the inputs are strings by default so if you want integers you need to convert as done below :

```
value1 = int(input("Please enter a string:\n"))
value2 = int(input("Please enter a string:\n"))
```